# How to check overlapping of objects?

Tags: python, pygame

What is the correct way to check if any of the objects `worker` overlaps with the objects of other classes (including `Worker`)? If it overlaps, it should change the trajectory.
Is there any built-in function in `pygame`? Any small example would be appreciated.

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()
machines = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()

# create multiple workers
for pos in ((30,30), (50, 400), (200, 100)):
    Worker("images/workers/worker_1.png", "images/workers/worker_2.png", pos, all_sprites, workers)

# create multiple machines
Crane("images/machines/excavator.png", (780,390), all_sprites, machines)

# create multiple geo-fences
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40)):
    GeoFence(rect, all_sprites, fences)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already use sprites and groups, it's quite easy to add.

Take a look at [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide).

I suggest creating a group for all sprites that should change the trajectory, as you said, and then use `spritecollide` in the sprite's `update` function to check for a collision:

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()
machines = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()
objects = pygame.sprite.Group()

# create multiple workers
for pos in ((30,30), (50, 400), (200, 100)):
    Worker("images/workers/worker_1.png", "images/workers/worker_2.png", pos, all_sprites, workers, objects)

# create multiple machines
Crane("images/machines/excavator.png", (780,390), all_sprites, machines, objects)

# create multiple geo-fences
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40)):
    GeoFence(rect, all_sprites, fences, objects)
```

and in the Worker's update method:

```
    # spritecollide returns a list of all sprites in the group that collide with
    # the given sprite, but if the sprite is in this very group itself, we have
    # to ignore a collision with itself
    if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, objects, False) if s != self):
        self.direction = self.direction * -1
```

If you want pixel perfect collision (instead of rect based collision detection), you can pass [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) as a fourth parameter to `spritecollide` if you make sure your sprites have a `mask` attribute

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain what is `objects` here?

Comment: @ScalaBoy just another `Group`, to contain all objects that should trigger a change of direction of the workers. Feel free to find a better name :-)

Comment: So, `objects` points to all objects, i.e. `fences`, `machines`, etc?

Comment: @ScalaBoy yes, that's the idea. You could of course call `spritecollide` multiple times with all the different groups... In the end, what's best depends of want you actually want in the end, and sometimes there's no best way to do something.